# How to use fontawesome in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, font-awesome

I want use fontawesome in my react project, i read [document](https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome) and add fontawesome with yarn:

```
$ yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
$ yarn add @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
$ yarn add @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

and create a component like as below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';

class Todo extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                font: <FontAwesomeIcon icon="coffee" />

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Todo;
```

But don't show icon, how fix this?

Comment: You could have a look at this library too. https://react-icons.netlify.com/#/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing some imports.

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faIgloo } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

library.add(faIgloo)
```

https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react

Answer (score 4):

If you want to reference the icon by its name you have to declare a *library*:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'
import { faCheckSquare, faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

library.add(fab, faCheckSquare, faCoffee)
```

Then use it like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'

export const Beverage = () => (
  <div>
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon="check-square" />
    Favorite beverage: <FontAwesomeIcon icon="coffee" />
  </div>
)
```

Otherwise, you can use explicit imports:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

const element = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee} />

ReactDOM.render(element, document.body)
```

All this bits of details are [explained here](https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome#usage). The above examples are from there.

Comment: How would you use it so you pass in a number - as in a shopping cart icon and overlay the number of items in cart on top of the icon?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you are spelling 'fortawesome' and not 'fontawesome'

Comment: Oddly, that's how it's specified in the docs. https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react

Comment: @isherwood Weird, I didn't check the docs, just glanced over his code. I wonder why they did that

Comment: IIRC fortawesome used to be their domain. Maybe before they got the big $ from the kickstarter

Answer (score -1):

Firstly you should use npm to install the react package

> npm i -g yarn
>
> yarn add react-native-fontawesome

After this you must import the data to start using in your project

```
import FontAwesome, { Icons } from 'react-native-fontawesome';
 
...
render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={{margin: 10, fontSize: 15, textAlign: 'left'}}>
        <FontAwesome>{Icons.chevronLeft}</FontAwesome>
        Text
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
},
```

if you want a more complete tutorial you can access the tutorial [clicking here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fontawesome)